# Upserting 50K records into big table (app. 350 columns) in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, c#, upsert

Using `C#` I'm trying to upsert from csv file (~ 55000 records) to a `postgresql` table with 350 columns. I'm just building the upsert statements from header and record which are comma separated. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.table(field1,fields2,field3, ..... ,field350) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,.......,?) ON CONFLICT(field1) DO UPDATE SET ...;
INSERT INTO public.table(field1,fields2,field3, ..... ,field350) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,.......,?) ON CONFLICT(field1) DO UPDATE SET ...;
INSERT INTO public.table(field1,fields2,field3, ..... ,field350) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,.......,?) ON CONFLICT(field1) DO UPDATE SET ...;
INSERT INTO public.table(field1,fields2,field3, ..... ,field350) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,.......,?) ON CONFLICT(field1) DO UPDATE SET ...;
....etc
```

I know about the `bulk insert Copy operation` which gave me for the inserts a very good peformance, but as mentioned, I need to run upserts and I didn't find anyway to run these upserts using this `COPY` thing.

Moreover, I can't run these in `transcations` because we want to check line by line and if a line fails, we don't want to fail the whole process, but log exception and continue with next line.

Using a `stored procedure` also didn't work because of the big number of columns that we have (350) which exceeds the allowed (100).

With my `C# script` i'm achieving 50K in 2 minutes, I know that this can be optimized. So is there any effecient way that you can suggest it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Use prepared statements. That will speed up execution, because the statement doesn't have to be planned every time.
- Use savepoints. That way, you can have a single big transaction and still recover from errors:

  - Set a savepoint every 100 rows or so.
  - If a row fails, rollback to the savepoint and redo everything up to the failing row, then skip that and start a new savepoint.

  If you have many errors, perhaps fewer than 100 rows would be preferable, so that you don't have to redo so much work. But setting a savepoint for every single row will also not be good for performance.
- `COPY` the data to a temporary table and then

  ```
  INSERT INTO finaltable
  SELECT * FROM temptable
  ON CONFLICT ...;
  ```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. Any example on prepared statements?

Comment: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html